# Multi-label Classifier underperforms individual classifiers

Tags: deep-learning, classification, image-classification, multilabel-classification

I originally trained multiple individual binary classifiers for each label of an image. Then, I realized I can train a single multilabel model for this task. I used binary_cross_entropy loss for this instead of categorical_cross_entropy, but besides for changing the loss function I made no major changes. However, I find that the multilabel classifier still substantially underperforms the individual label classifiers. Is this common and to be expected? Are there any tricks I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you mean *multilabel* and not *multiclass*? Because multilabel classification is equivalent to multiple individual binary lassifiers, whereas multiclass is a single model taking all the classes into account.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected for at least two reasons:

1. Extra supervision:

The multilabel classifier can use the extra information about other classes eg. by inferring "I want to find horses. I also know houses and dogs. While horses/houses are easy to divide, I have to be careful about the division of horses and dogs.". More concrete: Think of it as transfer learning. Eg. when using any kind of neural network, early feature-extraction layers profit from the extra loss and are learned more generally when you train a single model compared to many binary models.

2. Class balance

Classes in your multilabel problem are guaranteed to be more balanced than classes in your binary problems are.

Comment: ps.: ofc. O mean multiclass classifier and not multilabel classifier, as I am sure the questioner did.